# Bookmarklet to edit URL and add text

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I want to use a bookmarklet to edit my live URL so I can switch between preview and edit modes.

I have been able to use a bookmarklet to edit most of the url. However I also need to it to add text at the end of the url for it to work.
Example below

**Current URL:**

https://www.site.co.uk/part1/part2

**Preview URL**
https://author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en/part1/part2.html?wcmmode=disabled

It is the "html?wcmmode=disabled" I can't seem to figure out how to add.

My current code is:
javascript:(function(){var url=window.location.href;stringUrl=String(url);stringUrl=stringUrl.replace(/www.site.co.uk/, "author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en");document.location=stringUrl;})()

This currently loads the link as (when on https://www.site.co.uk/part1/part2)

https://author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en/part1/part2

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code has many redundancies that do not need to be there. Instead of using the entire url with `window.location.href` you can use [`window.location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname) to just get the path (everything after the first slash, in your example it would be `/part1/part2`). You can then prepend `https://author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en` to the path like so: `"https://author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en" + window.location.pathname`

For adding text to the end of the url, if the url is guaranteed to end with text like `part2` and will never end with a file extension like `part2.html` then you can simply just concatenate a string to the end of the url by doing `url + ".html?wcmmode=disabled"`.

This is a very simple piece of code that gets the job done but doesn't adapt to very many situations.

```
javascript:(function(){window.location.href="https://author-cms.net/content/site-co-uk/en"+window.location.pathname+".html?wcmmode=disabled";})();
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this over. Would you be able to provide the full code please? I'm not 100% sure what I'm currently doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I edited it with a very simple solution. If you need a more flushed out solution feel free to let me know.